# Popup panel showing up twice using OpenLayers for Android

Tags: openlayers-2, mobile, android

I use Moto Xoom (Android V3.0 touch pad) browse the example "OpenLayers with Sencha Touch", when I click button "LayerList", the associated popup panel doesn't show up smoothly. it will show once, then very quickly show up again. I tested other buttons, for example "Search" button and popup "search" panel, same issue happens.

It seems that it's something related to OpenLayers. Because another example "OpenLayers with JQuery Mobile" also has this.

I am wondering whether someone could give me some hints about what's happening underlying this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers 2.10 has not support for mobile/touch devices.
Openlayers 2.11 should improve with regard to this aspect, maybe you could try to rebuild the examples with OL 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

I do that with the 2.13 version, so if you need to install Python, look into the solution at [Creating popup in mobile OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74202/problem-creating-a-popup-in-mobile-openlayer)